# Why Editor reformats my code

Tags: tinymce, editor

I'm using TinyMCE Advanced and SyntaxHighliter plugins on my WordPress install.

Why does the editor change my inserted code, from:

```
[php]
<?php
/**
echo('code');
/**/
[/php]
```

to:

```
[php]
<!--?php <br ?-->/**
echo('code');
/**/
[/php]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `htmlspecialchars()` before sending content and`htmlspecialchars_decode()` before showing content on page, here is functions that you need to copy/paste to your functions.php :

```
function wp_po9568($content)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($content);
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','wp_po9568');
```

And:

```
function wp_po5689($content)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content','wp_po5689');
```

Wordpress by default comments out php tags.

Comment: This is so wrong. There is possibility that you dont want to convert everything. Adding a code to the_content is just wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter on your theme functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

This will remove extra P and line brake from short-code.
More details will found here http://dynamicweblab.com/2012/10/removing-extra-p-and-line-breaks-from-shortcodes-in-wordpress/